# Laravel Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I need your help in this topic, it concerns an error when trying to use mongodb with Laravel 5.1 project.

I installed mongodb 2.6 in windows successfully
I put the `php_mongodb.dll` in the ext folder of PHP 5.6.*
and I added the mongodb extension in the `php.ini` file but I still have this error

> class MongoDB/Driver/Manager' not found

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you run `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` In your project?

Comment: Hi, Yes sure and i put the mongodb serviceprovider in the app.php

Answer (score 0):

Please check your apache (32 bit or 64 bit) and download the correct.and try again . it may work.

Answer (score -1):

For PHP 7.2.4 on Windows this package worked!

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.5.1/windows

Please check your PHP version and article with this commend:

```
php -v
```

then download the zip file, extract the .dll in ext folder, run php again, create a php file with content:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

if you can find a mongodb section, then everything is fine.